# C++ elegant templates injection into interface

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, service-locator

I need some trick to implement c++ unsupportable: i need to mix dynamic and static polymorhism (virtual and template). What i need (some schematic code):

```
class IManager
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void Set();
    template<class T>
    T *Get();

protected:
    IManager *_parent;
};

class Manager1: public IManager{};
class Manager2: public IManager{};

// the main goal is a semantic:
IManager manager = Manager1;
// IManager manager = Manager2;
manager.Set<MyClass>();
MyClass *myClass = manager.Get<MyClass>();
```

This is a little bit looks like service locator. but it has some differences and i need a such interface declaration. i already have a such implementation, but without interface (it just configuratable by options in constructor, and i want to separate implementations of each interface)

Update:
For now i have 2 implementations:
1. I use interfaces, but it methods are cover all states of template paramteres via arguments. And also i have static function helpers, which convert template parameters and pass them to interfaces as arguments

```
class Manager: IManager{};
Manager manager;
Helper::Set<T>( manager );
Helper::Get<T>( manager );
```

1. i don't use interfaces, but inject all different implementations in one instance and configurate it by constructor arguments.
   Both solutions are ugly.

   class Manager{
   public:
       Manager( options );
   };

Comment: what do you mean with this code: `template<class T>
    void Set();` it doesn't seem need any typename T ?

Comment: this is schematic code. this type is required both for set and get

Comment: but why is it requirred for set ? it doesn't make sense for me ! there's nothing in the input or the output of the function taht depends on T. In such cases one **does not** use a template. So you want to achieve something but I can't see what.

Comment: i set information from passed type information

Comment: it's vague. What more precisely ? template are compile-time things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable with the Visitor design pattern.

Visitor injects new functionality into a hierarchy of classes. This need not be virtual and can be expressed as a function template with no problems.

The usual downsides of Visitor apply (the cyclic dependency), as do the usual fixes/workarounds (the acyclic dynamic visitor technique).

Here's a (regular, cyclic) implementation example, quickly thrown together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Manager1;
class Manager2;

class Visitor
{
  public:
  virtual void visit (Manager1*) = 0;
  virtual void visit (Manager2*) = 0;
};

class IManager
{
  public:
    template<class T> void Set(T* t);
    template<class T> T *Get();

    virtual void accept(Visitor* v) = 0;
};

class Manager1: public IManager
{
  public:
    template<class T> void Set(T*) 
    { std::cout << "Manager1::Set " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; }
    template<class T> T *Get() 
    { std::cout << "Manager1::Get " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; return 0; }
    virtual void accept(Visitor* v) 
    { v->visit(this); }
};

class Manager2: public IManager
{
  public:
    template<class T> void Set(T* t) 
    { std::cout << "Manager2::Set " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; }
    template<class T> T *Get()
    { std::cout << "Manager2::Get " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; return 0; }
    virtual void accept(Visitor* v) 
    { v->visit(this); }
};


template <class T>
class GetVisitor : public Visitor
{
  public:
    T* GetFunc(IManager* m) { m->accept(this); return t; }
    void visit(Manager1* m) { t = m->Get<T>(); }
    void visit(Manager2* m) { t = m->Get<T>(); }
  private:
    T* t;
};

template <class T>
class SetVisitor : public Visitor
{
  public:
    void SetFunc(IManager* m, T* tt) { t = tt; m->accept(this); }
    void visit(Manager1* m) { m->Set(t); }
    void visit(Manager2* m) { m->Set(t); }
  private:
    T* t;
};

template<class T> void IManager::Set(T* t)
{ SetVisitor<T> v; v.SetFunc(this, t); }
template<class T> T *IManager::Get()
{ GetVisitor<T> v; return v.GetFunc(this); }

class Foo {};

int main ()
{
  IManager* mgr1 = new Manager1;
  IManager* mgr2 = new Manager2;

  int a = 5;
  const char* b = "abc";
  double c = 1.0;
  Foo d;

  mgr1->Set(&a);
  mgr1->Set(&b);
  mgr1->Set(&c);
  mgr1->Set(&d);
  mgr1->Get<Foo>();

  mgr2->Set(&a);
  mgr2->Set(&b);
  mgr2->Set(&c);
  mgr2->Set(&d);
  mgr2->Get<Foo>();

}
```

It is possible to break the cycle with some `dynamic_cast`s, but each user of `Set` and `Get` will still depend on *all* `Manager` classes. This is how templates work in C++. If this is not acceptable, then templates perhaps are not the right tool for this job.

Comment: The visitor would need to have a virtual function per class. Each class would need to override a virtual function accepting a visitor. Would be interesting to see how you do that without virtual functions.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: you are mistaken. The visitor needs a virtual function per class which is not a template. The *visitee* needs a virtual function which is not a template either. The template here is the visitor class template itself.

Comment: i mean, that visitor will change code semantic (as i wrote in my answer the goal is to keep a such call semantic)

Comment: @n.m. The visitee has a virtual function void `accept(Visitor&)`. I.e. the type of the visitor is hardcoded, so you can't derive and extend the visitor if it does not employ virtual functions. It still works for one concrete visitor type, but I am not sure how useful that is, unless you are willing to add a new `accept` overload to the hierarchy of classes for each new visitor type. That may go out of hand and escalate quite quickly.

Comment: and also visitor will not solve the problem. it just own it. but ít will be neccessary to solve the same problem inside visitor

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: there is actually a virtual function per class in Visitor.

Comment: @deeptowncitizen: I'm not sure what do you mean by "change code semantic" and "just own it". I have updated my answer with somee working code. Does it solve your problem without breaking your semantic? If not, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: @n.m. that's great solution. and what about multithreading?  as i see i can make ManagerXXXX synchronized and it will be multithreaded?

Comment: I think the multithreading issue is orthogonal to the dynamic dispatch issue. Don't see any particular problem in making this all thread-safe.